# Jira attachment image and some other url is broken

Tags: jira

I have a jira installation in a dedicated server. I access it by ip address as I don't have any domain name now. The problem is image or other attachment url in any project issues are broken. For example, attachment of an image url is http://secure/attachment/10000/attachment_image.png but which should be http://1.2.3.4/secure/attachment/10000/attachment_image.png. The image is being uploaded because if I access the image directly then it shows the image is there.

I have other jira installation they are working fine, no problem at all. The difference of my other jira installation with this one is other have domain names, but this doesnt have. Not sure if this is happening for domain names or what. So if you know anything about this please help me!

Comment: Did you even try contacting Atlassian support? They're *very* good.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to set JIRA's Base URL (under the Administration tab, under Global Settings, under General Configuration).  [JIRA's documentation](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+JIRA+Options) has more details.